# Colored emojis in Chromium

Tags: chromium

This is *not* a Pi-specific question, but any Pi user will run into this problem eventually if they use it as a desktop computer.

I tried [this tutorial](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/enable-color-emoji-linux-google-chrome-noto), but it doesn't fully work, breaks some apps, and in my opinion looks horrible.

How do I get colored emojis to display in chromium-browser?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to remove the meta-stuff from your question - to focus on the actual question. Anyone who choses to vote to close as *off-topic* may do so without that anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has a color emoji font, Segoe UI. A nearly current version can be found [here](https://fontsdata.com/zipdown-segoeuiemoji-132714.htm).

But this is not a perfect solution. Segoe UI cannot display every single emoji in existence, so I use a combo of Segoe UI and [Noto Color Emoji](https://noto-website.storage.googleapis.com/pkgs/NotoColorEmoji-unhinted.zip).

And these commands will download, extract, and copy the two fonts to the .fonts folder:

```
mkdir ~/tmp
cd tmp
wget https://fontsdata.com/zipdown-segoeuiemoji-132714.htm 
wget https://noto-website.storage.googleapis.com/pkgs/NotoColorEmoji-unhinted.zip
mv zipdown-segoeuiemoji-132714.htm segoeuiemoji.zip
unzip segoeuiemoji.zip
unzip NotoColorEmoji-unhinted.zip
mkdir /home/pi/.fonts &>/dev/null
mv seguiemj.ttf "/home/pi/.fonts/Segoe UI.ttf"
mv NotoColorEmoji.ttf "/home/pi/.fonts/Noto Color Emoji.ttf"
fc-cache -f -v &>/dev/null
rm -r ~/tmp
cd
```

Check out this [emoji preview site](https://eosrei.github.io/emojione-color-font/full-demo.html), it should look like this:
[image]
As you can see, this is much improved over what it looked like before:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can install the color emoji font from Google:

```
sudo apt install fonts-noto-color-emoji
```

You will have to restart any programs for emoji to show up in them.

Answer (score 0):

I am having issues with this on a rpi 5 running the latest rpi OS.

No emoji's are displayed, even when I open the .ttf files in the font viewer application (installed along with font manager).

The whole thing is just blank squares, for NotoColorEmoji, NotoEmoji.

The Segoe UI Emoji's do work however in the viewer atleast.

Is there an alternative to Noto that might work?

Comment: Try installing the Color Emoji Font from the Pi-Apps store.

Comment: Sadly, no dice. Still have the same issue. If I look at the Noto fonts in font viewer, I can see that the characters seem to exist (the names come up when you hover over them) but they are just empty grey squares.